# using json as datatype in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to chang my AJAX script that have a text as datatype, into JSON.

the `datatype:"text"` was working well, so I tried to change it to this script:

In the PHP code:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

$emp_name = $_POST['d1'];
$pos = $_POST['d2'];
$sal = $_POST['d3'];

$insert = "INSERT into emp(name, pos, sal) VALUES (:emp_name, :pos, :sal)";
$insertStmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":emp_name", $emp_name);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":pos", $pos);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":sal", $sal);
$insertStmt->execute();

    //echo "success";
   while($row = $insertStmt->fetch())
   {
        $data[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

And here is what I changed in my AJAX script:

```
$("#btnClicked").click(function()
{
    var emp = $("#name").val();
    var pos = $("#pos").val();
    var sal = $("#sal").val();

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {d1: emp, d2: pos, d3: sal},
        dataType: "JSON",

        function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
});
```

I need to see the data first in the console.

Data are added to the server and will show in my html table when refresh, but they don't appear in the console.

Their is no error shown in the console.

So how to see them, and how to append my table with `json` returned data.

Comment: That's not a correct ajax call, have you read the documentation? It would for example suggest: `$.ajax({ }).done(function(response){ });`

Comment: Can you help with a sample script ?

Comment: I've just given you an example.

Comment: Are you see HTML format result in console ?

Comment: No, nothing is shown in the consle

Comment: add exit(); function below the echo json_encode($data); and check it

Comment: You can't fetch from an `INSERT` statement. You can only fetch from a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about jQuery but I think the function should be more like this with a `success` handler

```
$("#btnClicked").click(function(){
    var emp = $("#name").val();
    var pos = $("#pos").val();
    var sal = $("#sal").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {d1: emp, d2: pos, d3: sal},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(err){alert(err)}    
    });
});
```

Didn't notice the php code until pointed out by Barmar - instead of trying to return data from an insert statement perhaps you could send back your own array of data to the js function.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

$emp_name = $_POST['d1'];
$pos = $_POST['d2'];
$sal = $_POST['d3'];

$insert = "INSERT into emp(name, pos, sal) VALUES (:emp_name, :pos, :sal)";
$insertStmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":emp_name", $emp_name);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":pos", $pos);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":sal", $sal);
$insertStmt->execute();

echo json_encode( array('name'=>$emp_name, 'position'=>$pos, 'salary'=>$sal ) );
```